# Accumulate Points Values Based on Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one table that has a Name with the total points earned adjacent to it. I want to be able to sum up those points based on the name of the person. I'll add screenshots below.

So I would have this table on sheet 1
[image]

On another sheet I would have
[image]

Where I would want to sum up all the points earned by everyone on the previous sheet (first picture)

And so a final result would look something like this
[image]

Edit* I tried to use SUMIF because it made sense from what I read, but I was unsure with how to match the name to points

here is the excel formula I tried:

```
=SUMIF('Leaderboard by Category'!$B$3:$B$59,'Leaderboard by Category'!$B$3:$B$59)
```

Comment: whoops forgot to add in my formula that I tried, I did try SUMIF but I had 0's returned

Comment: Thank you! I added my attempt in

Comment: Why are the two arguments for SUMIF identical? More importantly, you need a range, criterion, and a sum range here, so three arguments. See the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

Comment: so this is where I was having trouble, would I have to have a criteria when using SUMIF? I just wanted to fill in the table with however many points a person would have

Comment: The criterion would be the Name. E.g, if `Name1` is in `A2`, then you'd use `A2` as the criterion and drag the formula down.

Comment: Got it from reading the documentation, I'll add my answer below! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
=SUMIF('Leaderboard by Category'!$B$3:$B$59,A2,'Leaderboard by Category'!$D$3:$D$59)
```

Leaderboard by Category is the sheet i reference

B$3:B$59 is the range of names that i'm matching

A2 is the criteria to match (so here I have all names in my A column)

Then D$3:D:59 is where I keep the scores

@BigBen thanks for the guidance through this!

Comment: It is always great to see someone answer their own question with just a bit of guidance, happy to help.